# Messages app on iPhone do not play alert/vibrate for SMS received from some numbers

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, notifications

I get no sound (or vibration) in my iPhone when a I receive a message from certain numbers. The number is not listed in my Contacts, it's a very short number sent containing SMS sent by my bank with some secure code or OTP to perform an operation with their services.

The iPhone is not in the Do Not Disturb mode and is not silenced. I sent a message to myself and heard the sound.

What is causing the sound to not play and how can I fix to get the sound back? My iPhone is running the current latest version of iOS 12.3.1.

Comment: Do you own any additional Apple device(s) and have turned on Text Message Forwarding under Settings app → Messages on your iPhone?

Comment: Yes, I have an iPad and a Mac. I checked the setting you mention and both devices are off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 12 and macOS Mojave introduced a feature called [Secure Code AutoFill](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/204/) which lets you conveniently fill the security code/OTP in the active text field when one is received via SMS.

If you use a Mac which is linked with the same Apple ID as your iPhone, and you have enabled Text Message Forwarding under Settings app → Messages, the secure code/OTP generally send by your bank can be easily entered in the appropriate field with a simple mouse click.

You can read about the feature in the linked article:

- [How to Use Secure Code AutoFill in iOS 12 and macOS Mojave](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/use-secure-code-autofill-ios-12-macos-mojave/)

> If you've enabled Text Message Forwarding on your iPhone, you can use the Secure Code AutoFill feature in macOS Mojave, too. The code should appear in Safari as an AutoFill option in the relevant field as soon as the SMS is delivered to Messages on your Mac.
>
> [image]
>
> iOS and macOS use local data detector heuristics to work out whether an incoming message carries a security code, and Apple says the Security Code AutoFill feature does not alter the security of this two-factor authentication method.

If you have such a setup, your iPhone doesn't play any sound or vibrate for the received message, and the SMS is automatically marked as read on your iPhone.

Comment: The forwarding setting is off. Actually, the message I get is not the final code, just a code to get valid code.

Answer (score 1):

It did. Now it doesn't. I was trying to change the message TONE/SOUND and when I did, and did a test auto fill, all I get is a vibrate now on the iPhone, nothing on the Mac. Used to have a pop up that I could choose to autofill a security code. Now. Crickets. Awesome. All I did was change the sound on the message. I'm been in notifications, allow, don't allow, focus, sounds, etc etc trying to figure out why it no longer works. Monterey. Was working fine. All I did was "just simply" change the tone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).